# PDO Exception while setting database username and password

Tags: mysql, laravel, pdo, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5 and mysql. The following error is coming while setting username and password.

> PDOException in Connector.php line 47: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access
>   denied for user 'some_username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

The content of my .env file is

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=4ZuW70AMILLsnvHkTJ1yraRoGqmx4Dzg

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=some_database
DB_USERNAME=some_username
DB_PASSWORD=some_password

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
```

and my config/database.php contains:

```
    'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'some_database'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'some_username'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'some_password'),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],
```

In phpMyAdmin I have created a user with same credentials. What might be wrong with it?

Comment: It's a MySQL permission problem. Try to connect from the console mysql -u some_user -h localhost -p

Comment: I am using windows ... Are you talking about command prompt?

Comment: Yes. Inside mysql installation folder there's a bin folder wich has mysql.exe (command line app to connect to a MySQL server)

Comment: It is showing 
`C:\xampp\mysql\bin>mysql -u hassan -h localhost -p _
Enter password: ********
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'hassan'@'localhost' (using password:
 YES)`

Comment: Well, there you have your problem. You have to grant access to the user you are trying to use (assuming hassan has password, otherwise you should remove -p from the command)